# How to collect all the "txt" and "log" files using find?

Tags: scripts, find

I currently have this script:

```
find . -iname '*.log' -print0 | xargs -0 tar zcf $file
```

To collect all the "*.log" files from a given directory. I would like to modify it to include also all the ".txt" files but I don't know how, this should be fairly simple right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right way. Try this:

`find . \( -iname "*.log" -or -iname "*.txt" \) -print0 | xargs -0 tar zcf $file`

Comment: For some reason when I try it only find .txt if I remove the `-prin0 | ....`  I get all the files listed though

Comment: You are right. Add parenthesis before -print0.

Comment: This will work up until a certain point. If the files found by find were to exceed the maximum argument length, xargs would pass as many files to tar as possible, then run it again with the remaining files. That means, the second tar would overwrite the archive the first tar made.

Comment: useless use of xargs

Answer (score 4):

This is almost the same as Raphael B.'s answer, but one that will also handle exceeding the maximum argument length. We do this by simply telling tar to read the filenames to archive from stdin (where there is no limit) instead of expecting them as arguments:

```
find . \( -iname "*.log" -o -iname "*.txt" \) -print0 | tar --null --files-from=- -zcf "$file"
```

Note that this is GNU specific. tar on other UNIX or UNIX-like systems does not understand `--null`, but the tar in Ubuntu is GNU tar, so it'll work fine there.

Comment: Good to know. BTW, I have this situation where the path is too long and it is not included in the search. To solve it I just cd to a closer path. Do you think this would help too in that situation? Eg I have `/some/path/other/other/other/file1.txt` and `/some/path/other/other/other/file2.txt`  and so on. So, the command dropped anumber of files. To workaround it, I first `cd /some/path/other/other` and execute the search from there.

Comment: Hm. The ancient tar format had a limitation on path length, but at least the posix tar format (pax) has no limitation. Not sure what format GNU tar uses by default.  How long is the path that gives you problems though? Could you check with `printf %s /some/path/other/other/other/file1.txt | wc -c` ? Also, do you see which program gives the error message? find, xargs or tar?

Comment: Yes, well done geirha. Thanks... I tested it with large numbers of filenames, and using xargs is certainly a trap... It unforgivingly runs tar again and overwrites the previous .tar, which of course has the same name... What an easy way to lose a LOT of data and get no warning! .. other than yours :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is the answer to useless use of xargs:

```
find \( -name "*.log" -or -name "*.txt" \) -exec tar zcf archiv2 {} +
```

I didn't test it for a lot of files - would be glad about a comment and a number, where it fails.

The pseudoargument, that you need to remember to place the -delete as last: Well, yes, you too have to remember to put | xargs ... as last, don't you?

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -regextype posix-extended -iregex '.*\.(log|txt)' -print0 | xargs -0 tar zcf $file
```

You can replace the `'.*\.(log|txt)'` with any [POSIX Extended](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_Extended_Regular_Expressions) regular expression.

The example matches:

> Any number of any character
>
> then a '.'
>
> then 'log' or 'txt'

Comment: I got: `find: invalid predicate -regextype` but this lead me to a working version `find . -regex '.*\.\(log\|txt\)'  -print0 ...etc `

Comment: That's strange. It works fine for me but doesn't match unless I specify the regexp type as `posix-extended`, `awk`, `gnu-awk` or `posix-egrep` using the `-regextype` parameter .

Answer (score 1):

What about this very simple approach:

```
find -iname '*.txt'; find -iname '*.log'
```